# Responsive horizontal scrolling table with fixed columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'd like to create a table that has two fixed columns, left and right and a horizontally scrollable section in the middle. An issue is that because the table is responsive, a width value can't be provided for the overflow and there could be any number of columns or rows.

See the mockup here - the middle section scrolls but the two columns on the left and right stay fixed.

[image]

I've already tried this by floating three different tables together but this is messy and very hard to maintain.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="scrollable-section">
    <table>
        <thead>
            ...
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically, I'd like to achieve this inside one table and I don't mind any added bits of JavaScript if neccessary using this markup:

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  margin-left: 100px;
}

table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table th {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
}

table td:first-of-type, table th:first-of-type {
/* fixed left column */
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  width: 100px;
  
}

table td:last-of-type, table th:last-of-type {
/* fixed right column */
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Row titles</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row title</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><button>Do something</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row title</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><button>Do something</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think this is not possible without nesting. One way would be to build the table with the two fixed columns as a three column table (2 fixed outer columns and one flexible in the middle). Define the middle column td with overflow-x: auto and then generate the table with the title-columns inside that td. (as a side note I would not use tables but div elements instead and style them with css table attributes)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616675/how-to-make-table-scroll-horizontally-with-fixed-first-and-last-columns

Refer This

Comment: Unrelated: I saw your vote for EDIT on https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20858659 . Wrong choice: this question is way too broad, and there is no chance that anybody but the OP can fix this question. It should have been closed as too broad. Please study the help for the triage queue and be more careful about your votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try  [datatable](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html) logic, there are some good contributions already available.

Comment: Should have known about this a long time ago thanks!